Custom env: catching a ball flying by a parabolic trajectory
I'm practicing to implement my own environment with Farama Gymnasium and PyGame,
the source code is available here
I implemented physics and a policy gradient method from the lesson: https://huggingface.co/learn/deep-rl-course/unit4/hands-on
The same code is capable of solving a cart pole problem.
But I'm struggling with making an agent to move a racket to catch a ball.
The environment:

a ball is thrown from left to right with some initial velocity
on the right side of the game field there is a racket that can move up or down
the reward is assigned when the ball hits the opposite side of the field. +10 if it hits the racket, -10 if it misses

I'm using a network with one hidden layer.
After the training, the platform either goes up or to the bottom and stays there.
My idea was that it learns a concept of gravity and a parabolic curve, or at least tries to follow the Y-coordinate of the ball,
but that doesn't happen.
Do you have any hints on how to tune my parameters or reward function?
Any help is appreciated.

You have to include the code as text in the question. See What topics can I ask about here?: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."
